# Can I restore my Macbook?

Tags: macbook, restore, system-restore

I was using my Macbook perfectly and suddenly when I restarted it, it went off forever and I had no choice but to re-install via DVD which came with it. I lost my data

Comment: Did you keep a backup?

Comment: No I couldn't. I was about to do that.

Comment: If you had tried to get the data off before installing over it, you had a good chance if the drive was accessible. Now, it is impossible from a practical standpoint. Maybe a forensic lab could, but it would cost a fortune to recover overwritten data.

Comment: When you are unable to access your data due to a broken operating system, do not do anything if you want to have a chance to ever get your database. Go on the forensic tour by either trying yourself with recovery tools or walking to a computer store and hear what it would cost you, if it goes to a forensic lab they should first create you a report of how much it would cost...

Comment: Forensic data recovery was unlikely to be necessary in this case, if a simple DVD reinstall fixed the problem. At this point in time, Apple considers hard-drives to be user-replaceable, which means that you are within your rights to pull off the back of the laptop, whip the hard-drive out, and attach it to a different computer. Your local nerd will be happy to do this for a small fee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you didn't keep a backup, then no. Your data is gone. Forever. Especially assuming you've used your MacBook after restoring it. This makes it difficult, if not impossible, to restore using special disk restoration tools.

Comment: OK any tools to recover XCode data?

Comment: @UmairAshraf: No, you can't! What part of this answer doesn't make that clear?

Comment: @UmairAshraf: Haha, so you're saying that you want Apple to do the impossible?

Comment: Also, clearly you're the one at fault for not keeping a backup. Apple can't do anything to fix carelessness ;)

Comment: @UmairAshraf: Apple already [did something about it](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1427)

Comment: Did you do an "Erase and install?" because that would be the only way you could have lost that data from a simple system recovery... the OS X installer defaults to "Archive and install" which would have preserved your data.

Comment: Umair, how did you ever think that reinstalling something will magically keep all of your data? Interestingly enough, as @Dustin G. said, IIRC the installer will *not erase the drive* as long as you don't go ahead and tell it to. See my other question here: [I reinstalled OS X and the system was the same as before](http://superuser.com/questions/257153/i-reinstalled-os-x-and-the-system-was-the-same-as-before)